# Algorithm to find product

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I encountered this problem at a coding challenge and was not able to solve it. This is the problem statement:

Given an array of transaction costs t, return an array of expected costs e such that it is 0 if product of all transaction costs in t except e[i] is even, else it is 1(i.e for any element in t[i], find product of all elements of t except t[i]. If that product is even, result for that t[i] is 0 else 1).

For example t = [1, 2, 3, 4], e = [ 0, 0, 0, 0]

Explanation: for t, all products are even:[24, 12, 8, 6]

Constraint: do it in O(n) and without division.

FYI, I did it in O(N^2) but couldn't solve it in O(N)

My solution:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] res = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        int prd = 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
            if(i == j) {
                continue;
            }
            prd *= arr[j];
        }

        if((prd & 1) == 0){
            res[i] = 0;
        }else {
            res[i] = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's interesting. Did you have...a question?

Comment: Can you post the code and tell what the problem is?

Comment: *I'm not going to show you any code, but I did it in O(N^2)* reads a lot like *Teacher, I did do my homework, but my dog ate it!*

Comment: How did you do it in O(N²)?

Comment: Added my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need division; all you need is a simple odd/even check.  However you care to do this is fine; for instance, mask off everything but the final bit.

Very simply, if all elements are odd, then `e` is a vector of 1's.  If one element is even, `e` is a vector of all 0's except for that one position, which is a 1.  If more than one element is even, then `e` is a vector of 0's.

This requires a single pass through `t` (which is **O(N)**) to find the quantity of even elements; then you can generate `e` in **O(N)** time

Comment: Great solution!! thanks a lot!